# Is it possible to connect Macbook Pro 2020 to 5.1 sound bar with HDMI?

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers

Bluetooth or AUX doesn't support channel separation. So wanted to connect via HDMI for surround sound but it's not getting detected.

Comment: Which sound bar? Your Mac doesn't have 'native' HDMI -- it's just got Thunderbolt/USB C ports, doesn't it? So how are you connecting to the soundbar? It may depend on the characteristics of the hub, adaptor or cable you've got inbetween.

Comment: @benwiggy sony htrt3. I'm connecting via type c to hdmi adapter